# Formal proof to $ A \setminus {B}^\complement = A \cap B $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I got the below equality from somes draws of Venn diagram, but I'm not able to build a formal proof to this. How to make it?

$ A \setminus {B}^\complement = A \cap B $

Comment: What definitions of $\cap $,  $\complement $, and $\backslash$ do you have? Do you have experience writing other proofs?

Comment: @MarkS., the classics definitions of intersection, complement and difference, respectivaly. And I have a bit experience, but I want be sure if there a proof to make this equality real.

Comment: One way of showing two sets are equal is by mutual inclusion.  Suppose $x \in A \backslash B^C$, then demonstrate that $x \in A \cap B$.  Then suppose that $x \in A \cap B$, then demonstrate that $x \in A \backslash B^C$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, yes, I throught about the mutual inclusion, but I'm thinking in a proof with only manegement of sets.

Answer (score 3):

In order to prove $$A \setminus {B}^\complement = A \cap B$$

You need to show two things.

Every element of $$A \setminus {B}^\complement$$ is an element of $$A \cap B$$

and vice versa.

Let $x$ be an element of $$A \setminus {B}^\complement$$

That means $x$ is in $A$ and $x$ is not in  ${B}^\complement$

Therefore $x$ is in $A$ and $x$ is in $B$ that is $x\in A\cap B$

You can finish the rest easily.

Answer (score 1):

$A\setminus B^\complement=A\setminus (X\setminus B)=A\cap(X\setminus (X\setminus B))=A\cap B$.

Answer (score 0):

Just do definitions: $A \cap B = \{x \in U| x \in A \land x \in B\}$.

$A \setminus B^c = \{x\in A| x \not \in B^c\} = \{x\in U|x \in A \land x \not \in B^c\} = \{x\in U|x \in A \land (\lnot (x\not \in B))\} = \{x \in U|x \in A \land x \in B\}$>

So $A\cap B$ and $A\cap B^c$ both describe the same set by definition.